# Infinite scroll repeats posts in custom loop in single.php

Tags: pagination

I'm feteching recent posts with infinite scroll in single.php.

My single.php code looks like:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; /* end loop */ ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'recent-posts'); ?>
```

The recent-posts.php code is:

```
<? $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$this_post = $post->ID;
query_posts(array('post__not_in' => array($this_post), 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'paged' => $paged,));
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
....
<?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Everythinhg thing is working except the infinite scroll repeats the first set of 9 posts again and againt when I scroll down. I check the course code and found that pagination has a problem. It put the paging the end of post url. I've tried by adding Wp_reset_query in single.php as you can see in above mentioned code, but it didn't work either.

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/2013/07/current-post-example/page/2/" class="next">
```

Comment: What infinite scroll? Is this a plugin? If so, provide a link? Is this code you've written? Or adapted? If so, post it.

Comment: Yes infinite scroll is a jquery plugin available for wordpress too. The code I've written above is exactly what I'm using in my template files. Now after thinking again and again I strongly believe its not infinite scroll causing this problem. Its something else. Because the link of pagination isn't right. It should appear `<a href="htp://mysite.com/page/2/">`. I can't figure it out the problem with my php code.